# Employees for Merchant in E-commrece?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an e-commerce project that contains there type of user `admins`,`merchants` and `normall user` in merchant section I need to make employees for merchant, like each merchant will have many employees with him and I'm confused between two structures for database `first one`:

In the same merchants table add another column named ( merchant_id ) it belongs to the parent of merchant.

```
id - name - email - password - merchant_id
```

`The second`:

Make a separate table like ( employees ) that the merchant has many employees.

```
id- name- email - password - merchant_id
```

The problem that I'm confused with is like when I give the `employees` permissions!

please guy's any suggestions for something like this probelm ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a diagram to show my point of view. Please consider the following image:
[image: diagram]

Explaining the diagram:

1. A merchand hasMany Employees;
2. An employee belongsTo a merchand (foreign key merchand_id to tbl_merchands);
3. An employee belongsTo a permission (foreign key permission_id to tbl_permissions);
4. A permissions hasMany employees;

Code the relations in the models and you are good to go. To validate if a user has permission to access some Route(), you can use a middleware.

**NOTE**: I created a tbl_permissions because of your request. Maybe I would rename to tbl_groups (admins, users, etc) and use the table globally.

Hope it guides you. Regards!

COMMENT #1:
To control the page access you may use a middleware. You can create a table for products with foreign keys to merchand_id and employee_id. To get products associated to an employee, you need to create a Model plus the relation to the products. To retrive the data, do `Employees::find($employee_id)->products`. Hope you know how to code in laravel otherwise you will have an hard time coding this tips.

Comment: Thank you so much, but there are two problems here ( i don't know the logic of them ). First: how can I make the merchant the his employee login in the same page of merchant login? Second: as you know it's E-commerce with muti-store, so the products of merchant  should be belongs to the main merchant or the employees and if to main merchant how can I get the products when the one of the employees login !?

Comment: Add merchand_id and employee_id to products table will be messy way!  Cuz I need to check whether this is the main merchant or employees and bring the products!

And yeah I can do the code but I need to be at least a good plan!

Comment: Or even like when I create a new product how can check the merchant weather  it's main merchant or employee. and sorry for keep it long on you!

Comment: Well, by the comments, you really need to sit and think/design a db structure first. I only suggested a solution, now you take it and adapt or develop you own ;)